# Command Line: "php" wrong or cannot be found

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning symfony for some weeks now. Everything went well. But since yesterday I cannot use **php** or **composer** in the terminal of Visual Studio Code (1.39.2) or in the native Command Line Tool of Windows.

In the actual lesson I should create a database like this in the CLI:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

In the .env-file I set the database like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://musa:musa@127.0.0.1:3306/zbase
```

But I get an error in the command line tool:

```sh
php: Die Benennung "php" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programs erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise 
des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (php:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

translated in english with DeepL (hope the translation makes sense)

```
php: The name "php" was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or whether the path is correct (if any), and repeat the procedure.
In line:1 character:1
+ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (php:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**What I tried**

- I tried to reinstall *XAMPP* and *WAMP* several times
- I tried to set the right path in the *Advanced system settings* in Windows

[Link to the screenshot](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/e64e969d-2789-4575-a405-cb3effea4f21/Untitled.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAT73L2G45EI7PXFFY%2F20191023%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191023T130254Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEA0aCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJIMEYCIQDZlMPOVa2jDbdAPf36ldx%2BDuzjl3jjeH7piyr2UmoEDwIhAKkbCqya5zSpuKBHNR0ltVmQWTyWw8c6UXPjoUAgtkYDKtoDCBYQABoMMjc0NTY3MTQ5MzcwIgx10qWhKD1SL5jm2%2BEqtwPz095vCNGNMglnaqw0x77XhdF6IAwGQizkia38047YmYtbgo90e2URc%2BmNkyS8nII1GuHoZ3kv9HWcmj%2B5NysNpNxIop4scEwrFYnqBPc1PDuVjddpJAbOzRJ9ZpWoR%2B8wx2%2FemrU1i5%2Bnj93D6UQZxKcOhFXJ7lLndKRuGKm5MbA3p2GSimuKc%2FB%2FCr%2BsdjznUCT3MuBijyY3XFZ9YK0%2BvM8rtskWkj6bZxcZ4UkB04%2BG9pNmN%2BnNU5Z5dntjC77gxgBMOyKr8FvaFbY25aszjn4ZvL7uq9MAUiCtWL%2BhX21p1t9VN5dKNAx4US6886%2BPo0ZTUR%2Fio3u4LZ8jk7cbbJYoxy8MRZpm1qqS6qoNK7CYG8MZiYzXB60UxD1w37RXYDj9kqJSm5nuXVls2UpL5rv1y39%2BRdBOI1Qm0A5YzAiEKWy4smAIQrPfbF3ngI%2BiZMTKZ4aolkcREkY8%2FsvIhbB%2BvRG09iIb4stZ7UPvs4%2BpfWr%2FqEbmhmSFN0XhLQf%2BcC99FPrp1OCVHPGImCIIwFezqAvvbNDuQQ9MXJvaV0UNuz6%2BYM%2B9QRrwU5nBl73Eyt7kVttqMPGMwe0FOrMBWxNn%2FMvpFaOqc2tsihX%2BGG%2FicAu4LCpkfLrP9WbTVqNyD9G3V86oFLqgGCWZ9znU8XI1xDJ4XIIJAQQnCd4ZzkJuB74jVzksJVuFoGTGQ6oUZzqEpMBSHEdGjagN4ngebh2ue81Or8B4qqNVYKT4b921RmFbM2pN0EyvgiW4Dr%2BIKVp0rT4xLRvJopT%2F227TmiyPzTFunzcB9O7ViNdEH7lIszqgXssCmdliFMUxMP5mNc8%3D&X-Amz-Signature=bfd146c4c53e2fc60cc9b4c4dd528b6114a8feef59308fbd99421e89853e6887&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22Untitled.png%22)

But when I try to check the used PHP-Version with this command, it seems to be a PHP installed.

```sh
symfony local:php:list
```

[Link to the screenshot](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/f70b534b-1d95-4710-938f-83e81e6d3d71/Untitled.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAT73L2G45AQHQTU5F%2F20191023%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191023T085904Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAcaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD5y2lDDhhDJjauV40PHzi6CJ4vz%2B26daFREDGwdmA8RgIgYK6EIHgdIE5tpEQIt5CuKF%2BqQtsRvNJiE175L9Tw3l0q2gMIEBAAGgwyNzQ1NjcxNDkzNzAiDCvpvg%2B3hyKoFlhB1Sq3A41ugwjx9jOJS5egZXYsJbOEjR8CY2qruvj3HmysJCmkPxCi6Gk%2BfQIMfzFvVRlHP64Yt7QOW2ajolG4MTjwUCo%2BhWDIw52JGnLgz%2BToXMLRWDFVz3PGpRQYklx%2FqIpCU8uqNaZyUULkzlBq4jZh%2B%2Beq6hlmNJW3sM5Q0qBS7icK%2BFmzwhD7emkE5fKd%2FrEHI7f9CAemwONoIY7%2FkEgz%2FIZwZ3GOqvyyyOPZN60jpYKZ117dwu%2BGsIUlLmUYADKqbGkhMxdI7kTVrZwQ5g%2FKeIqKiEW92mZKiQ5Hj%2Ffa35rsz4YGoC4BvfK5d1wk4MQ4pMxWbKEPjxTIhXmo0Tns2A9cEoUUvZfGO95rC67uKJDMbLfLSlbWaAOLTZvu%2FoInfDr%2Bp4aaCb7YYKuxtsz3xAc67GJhA4BhvXcg42tsE1tlxuVw%2Fo4wbHDsrljtCsZW25XvcEEz2Q5N1z5pP53fG31mD1ZPSO267uTZjFG2d9dEFPFo%2B0OU%2FJfX3Hj37oC8dTsTxc5zjZblk93T9%2Fqtv6FfJ%2FwughAPpIKhRvq8V%2Bqo7bZEwYd%2FobXHltrUBVZYvywQVIw8F%2B8woey%2F7QU6tAEHP%2FWDF3Y1C%2B%2FOfIpJudzp7T9JJF2ZhcFYigXM%2BSU%2FPxXTpYRBnKLDt9j%2BIKUtQhphoDov9V6Q06FiEEC1YjN1zpaA3Ee4vH148VuXH1INX7zBWOg28MBAWIVnGdjT3qem1BMU%2Fiynjs56aOHxo2To42xUuPKePJf9uAAlmwqtranytc8wzJDlY1yn%2BD2B%2BgT0M7ppzbxxQI2rMA988h%2FxHaiHNDZP7yA4lDnyB%2BuGDYyW1MI%3D&X-Amz-Signature=32e31394f095049f3d7f23241ea31577b1cc12a7116e0dceae4016c161b2da1d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22Untitled.png%22)

There is another error in the CLI. For:

```
php -v
```

I get the message:

```
Der Befehl "php" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

again translated in english:

```
The "php" command is either misspelled or
could not be found.
```

Regards,
Musa

Comment: Hi, could you past the PHP error in English please :) ?

Comment: @qdequippe: Sure. :) Now there are the translated error messages. I also inserted another one, when i enter `php -v`.

Comment: thanks, did you try just call `bin/console doctrine:database:create` without `php`?

Comment: Yes. Windows tries to open it and asks me "How should the file be opened?" and gives me a list of programs (like Editor, Firefox, and so on)

Comment: No one who can give me a hint, where to search?

Comment: Try `symfony run bin/console doctrine:database:create`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. I tried it with VS Code and the Command Line Tool of Windows. Both say:
**exec: "bin/console": file does not exist**